# Magit - How to expand all and collapse all sections in magit-status

Tags: magit

Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> on a single unstaged file shows or hides details pertaining to that file.

How do I show & hide (toggle) details of all unstaged files at once?

I did come across outline-hide-sublevels via `M-x`. But I would like to know a key combination to do this in a toggle fashion.

I also typed <kbd>?</kbd> to check the keybinding shortcuts for the magit-status area but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you want <kbd>M-TAB</kbd> `magit-section-cycle-diffs`

> Cycle the visibility of diff-related sections in the current buffer.

https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Section-Visibility-1

Comment: Fantastic, I did look through the docs but must have missed this. Thanks very much

Comment: @orion Happy to hear that's what you were looking for. If this fully answers your question you can click the checkmark to the left of this answer to "accept" it so others know the question is complete.

Comment: Every operating system or window manager I have used in the last 15 years has `M-TAB` bound to window switching...

Comment: Actually what I was looking for was M-2 or M-4 from anywhere in the magit buffer to expand and collapse all, which is documented in the link Jack provided

Answer (score 19):

Another method (if you do not want to change key bindings for the <kbd>M-TAB</kbd> solution) is to position your cursor on the line with the section heading, e.g. "Unstaged changes", and press <kbd>2</kbd> to collapse all changes in that section, or <kbd>4</kbd> to expand them.

It also works for collapsing/expanding changes per subsection/file.

Comment: `2` - is exactly I needed, many thanks!

Comment: In particular, `2` works anywhere within the section.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>S-TAB</kbd> (that's `shift`) to invoke `magit-section-cycle-global` for a coarse-granularity full-expand and -collapse.

Answer (score 0):

The following works as an replacement to `M-tab`.

```
(define-key magit-mode-map [(control >)] 'magit-section-cycle-diffs)
```

`M-tab` doesn't work on most MS Windows systems